# reg add invalid syntax cmd

Tags: java, cmd, registry, tomcat7

I want to change a registry key on commandline, but it says always wrong syntax. Maybe someone can help me. Here is my code:

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\tomcat7\Parameters\Java /v Jvm /t REG_SZ /d C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7_2\bin\client\jvm.dll /f
```

I want to change the java path. Do I need anything for the spaces in the path(s)?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\tomcat7\Parameters\Java" /v Jvm /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7_2\bin\client\jvm.dll" /f
```

Values with spaces should be quoted to be handled as only one argument.

Comment: That's what I already tried...didn't work :( Also tried single quotes - same result.

Comment: @Tobi123, for me the posted line, copied and pasted in cmd window, creates the indicated registry key with the indicated value. What do you mean with *didn`t work*? What error do you get? What is the difference between what you get and what you expect?

Comment: The named registry key already exists and has the value "auto".
I want to change the value to the specified path (C:\...).
When I post the command in my cmd windows I get the information "Invalid Syntax".

EDIT: Now it passed successfully...I can't say why it wasn't working before. 

Thanks for your help!